# Regex Problem in Extractor Regular Expression - JMeter

Tags: regex, parameters, jmeter

I'm using the regular expression extractor in JMeter to extract data from a parameter.
However, the data is not being extracted.

Response:

```
{
    "access_token": "8d06ba17-2e51-31d2-aa55-25e4a3ecd33b",
    "expires_in": 7200
}
```

Extractor:

```
Name reference: token
Regular expression: "access_token": "(.+?)"
Match: $1$
```

Request parameter use

```
v1/api/users?client=${token}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `access_token` is a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)-like structure so you can use the following regular expression instead:

   ```
   ([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-]([A-Fa-f0-9]){12})
   ```

   [image]
2. Alternatively you can try to secure yourself by adding optional whitespace meta character like:

   ```
   "access_token"\s?:\s?"(.+?)"
   ```

   [image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

---

3. And finally your response is in [JSON](http://json.org/) format so it makes more sense to use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/), the relevant [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as:

   ```
   $.access_token
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Hi guy!!
Thank you! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use instead [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) with `JSON Path Expressions` as `$.access_token`

> JSON PostProcessor enables you extract data from JSON responses using JSON-PATH syntax. This post processor is very similar to Regular expression extractor. It must be placed as a child of HTTP Sampler or any other sampler that has responses. It will allow you to extract in a very easy way text content

Comment: Success !! Thank you! I used this JSON extractor !!! Very thanks!!!

"JSON Path Expressions Semi-colon separated JSON-PATH expressions (must match number of variables)"
I did not understand! Could you explain?

Comment: @EstevaoFPM I changed quote from JMeter documentation